# What is Key Error 111 In sentence transformers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am working on product matching projects by extracting semantic text in the Data Frame.
I used Sentence Transformers lot of times for encoding the text but now i am getting the problem like Key Error: 111.
I tried so many ways but i am not able to solve it

```
a = model.encode(H['Text_HE'], convert_to_tensor=True)
b = model.encode(DN['Text_DNE'], convert_to_tensor=True)
c = model.encode(TH['Text_TE'], convert_to_tensor=True)
d = model.encode(TH['Text_TE'], convert_to_tensor=True)
```

[About the Key Error:111.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo0ft.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The key error is related to pandas, not sentence transformers. Verify that you can access all the DataFrame (assuming that H, DN and TH are dataframes) columns before passing them to the encode method.